# Examinations results as a mysql Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Stack Overflow family.
I have a table called grades, which has three columns. Index number coursecode and grades as shown below.

[image]

I want the courses listed in the coursecode column to appear each on it's own column together with it's corresponding grade. I tried and it gave me this...
[image]

with the code below
[image]
But I am stack here.... I need a result that looks like this

[image]

I am using mysql as the database on a Wamp server. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I would expect to see a group by and why a view?

Comment: P. Salmon, I want it to be a standalone table (view) and not embed php code into it. I would then fetch the data easily from the table